# Intersection of a sphere and a cylinder

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, curves, algebraic-curves

> Take the Viviani curve intersection of a sphere and a cylinder. Analytically explain what happens to the intersection curve if you keep the radius of the sphere constant, fix one side of the cylinder at the origin, and change the radius of the cylinder. Especially, discuss the cases when the radius of the cylinder goes to $0$ and $\infty$.

It was intuitively quite clear to me that if you keep $R$ (radius of the sphere) constant, and vary $r$ (radius of the cylinder), then the intersection curve tends to two points when $r\to 0$ and it tends to the longitudinal great circle when $r\to \infty$.

But, I had to solve it analytically, and so, I wrote the equations
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2\\x^2+y^2=rx$$
Substituting the value of $x^2+y^2$ from the second equation into the first, we get
$$z^2=R^2-rx$$
which looks like a parabola on the $ZX-$plane!!!

Am I going wrong anywhere? If not, then how can I proceed from here?

Comment: If the radius of the cylinder is $r$ then equation of the cylinder is $x^2 + y^2 = 2 rx$. Also note that the projection of the intersection curve in the zx-plane is indeed part of $z^2 = R^2 - 2rx$ and in xy-plane it is $x^2 + y^2 = 2 rx$. You can parametrize the intersection curve to express more concisely.

Comment: For this specific question, just show that as radius goes to $0$, $x^2 + y^2$ nears zero and so do $x$ and $y$. Then from the equation of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$, you get $x = y = 0, z = \pm R$ which are two points. As $r$ goes to $\infty$, show that the cylinder for finite $R$ is plane $x = 0$ and that gives circle $y^2 + z^2 = R^2$ as the intersection.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks. You can also post the parametrized idea as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r=0$, $x=y=0$ and $z=\pm R$.

And if $r\to\infty$, as $x=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}r\le\dfrac{R^2}{r}\to 0$ the curve tends to the circle $x=0,y^2+z^2=R^2$.

---

The projection of the intersection curve on the plane $xz$ is inscribed on a parabola (one or two arcs).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve#/media/File:Viviani-fenster-xyz.svg

Comment: Oh! It was quite easy then! Thanks (+1)!